# UIDevice's beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications doesn't work well

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I have a subview in a subclass of UIView. When the device is rotated I want the subview to remove. This is my code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)orientationChanged
{
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

My problem is that even if the device is tilted a little bit, or put on for example a table the subview removes. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Does your app support multiple interface orientations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't track the device orientation.  Track the interface orientation.  Use [`UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW45) instead of `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, and get the new interface orientation out of the notification's `userInfo`.  (You won't have to do `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` if you track interface orientation.)

Comment: is there a way to force this to call? I have a version of a view for Portrait I need to display when its in portrait, but the default it sets up is for landscape...